# fail2ban / FirewallD error: invalid port/service `1-65535' specified

Tags: centos, iptables, firewalld, fail2ban

I am running a CentOS 8.4 server. When I do a `systemctl status firewalld` I see the daemon is active and running, but I see the following error repeated five times:

> ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.8.4 (nf_tables): invalid port/service `1-65535' specified

FirewallD version is 0.8.2.

The error disappears when I stop `fail2ban`.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Thank you.

Comment: iptables' port range is x:y not x-y . This might be related to your problem, but without context can't tell.

Comment: Dug a little deeper and found that the issue is related to `fail2ban`. If I stop `fail2ban` and restart `firewalld`, errors disappear. The problem indeed seems to be port range selector but `fail2ban` is supposed to be able to handle it. I see this issue was fixed last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed when package updates became available.