# CentOS 8: Which repo has the latest version of FirewallD?

Tags: centos, yum, dnf, firewalld

I am running a CentOS 8.4 server with the following repos:

```
~]$ dnf repolist
repo id          repo name
appstream        CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
baseos           CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS
epel             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
extras           CentOS Linux 8 - Extras
remi-modular     Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
remi-safe        Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
```

The current `fireWalld` version is 0.8.2, which is pretty old and is causing some issues with `fail2ban`. I'd like to update it. When I run `sudo dnf update firewalld` it cannot find any newer versions and simply returns the usual "nothing to do" message. Which repo do I need? Thanks.

Comment: What issues is it causing? I haven't seen any problems with fail2ban caused by firewalld in CentOS 8 or RHEL 8.

Comment: When I turn on `fail2ban`, `firewalld` start to complain about this error: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659222/fail2ban-firewalld-error-invalid-port-service-1-65535-specified and I suspect updating `firewalld` might fix it. What version of `firewalld` are you running on CentOS and how did you update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firewalld`: No CentOS 8 updates found, but it's fairly easy to build **el8** packages from a later "source.src.rpm" : `firewalld-0.9.4`.

Use the old / simplified "rpmmacros" (the CentOS 8 version doesn't match the "year 2021 firewalld.spec")  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13

From Fedora 34 update
`$ wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/34/Everything/source/tree/Packages/f/firewalld-0.9.4-1.fc34.src.rpm`

```
$ rpm -Uvh firewalld-0.9.4-1.fc34.src.rpm
# dnf builddep /home/name/rpms/SPECS/firewalld.spec

$ cd /home/name/rpms/SPECS/    
$ rpmbuild -bb firewalld.spec
.
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/firewalld-0.9.4-1.el8.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/python3-firewall-0.9.4-1.el8.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/firewalld-filesystem-0.9.4-1.el8.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/firewall-applet-0.9.4-1.el8.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/firewall-config-0.9.4-1.el8.noarch.rpm
```

Link to packages https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KLZM0ZrxygWMMPLMrSEB5UEsJIjsnSBJ?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this mean every CentOS install out there is stuck on FirewallD 0.8.2 unless they manually update with rpms? I was under the impression that CentOS was still being maintained fairly regularly. Is that no longer the case?

Comment: RHEL, CentOS : Package major versions are usually not changed to a new version. Instead the packages are updated, patched with the latest security fixes and goodies from newer versions. E.g. the kernels are constantly updated with security patches and new drivers. See "minor version".  Example  kernel-3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7 : **1160.36.2** is the minor version = "patch level".

Comment: EL8 : `firewalld` is now minor version **7**  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/ ..... Some of the other "firewalld" packages are in the AppStream.repo http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/

Comment: After further research I see that CentOS is virtually dead. It's no longer in lockstep with Red Hat and has moved from downstream to upstream. I hadn't realized the recent changes. Note: It might be best if you removed the last part - I don't think we wan to encourage people to click on Google Drive links.

Comment: I've said this before and I'll say it again: It isn't a good idea to install packages from other distributions. Most of time, you'll be alright but all it takes is one mistake and you'll have an unresolvable dependency that renders your system unusable. It may be fine at the time but it's always possible that other packages will be released that will conflict. You've accepted the answer but this isn't good advice.

Comment: Nasir, I 100% agree with you and that's not how I understood the answer. What I understood is that he was simply demonstrating how to wget and update using Fedora as an example, meaning updating a Fedora system with a Fedora package. I would never install a Fedora package outside Fedora. The accepted answer should be edited and everything below the linuxquestions.org link should be deleted.

Comment: All {Redhat RHEL / Redhat CentOS} packages and update patches are from the in-house 'Redhat Fedora' OS. (RHEL8 is based on Fedora 28).  An fc34.src.rpm is simply the original source.tar.gz + a file.spec to be used to reproduce packages for a later Fedora or for RHEL. .... Example {firewalld-0.8.2.tar.gz + firewalld.spec (+ some patches)}

Comment: @KnudLarsen It is a different version of the package from a different operating system. You may be fine this time but all it takes is one time to mess up a system due to conflicts and dependencies that can't be resolved. Your answer gives terrible advice that has a history of doing this which is why it's never a good idea to advise installing packages from the repos of other operating systems and/or versions. What part of that don't you understand?